# Click Listener for items in RecyclerView working only on clicking twice

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in an activity which shows some products and works like a shopping cart activity. As list item I am using 2 text views and an image button.
For the button, I have implemented a click listener for that image button. But whenever that button is clicked **for the first time** for a certain list item, it **needs to be clicked twice**. I have tried using ontouchlistener too. Kindly help me resolving the issue. Here is the code of my adapter and xml.

Adapter

```
private class servicesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<servicesAdapter.servicesViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> pairArrayList;
    Context context;

    public servicesAdapter(ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> pairArrayList, Context context) {
        this.pairArrayList = pairArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        selectedList=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public servicesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.garage_service_list_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new servicesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final servicesViewHolder servicesViewHolder, int i) {
        Pair<String,String> current=pairArrayList.get(i);
        servicesViewHolder.Service.setText(current.first);
        final int j=i;
        servicesViewHolder.ServicePrice.setText(current.second);
        servicesViewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(servicesViewHolder.imageButton.getTag()=="Add") {
                    selectedList.add(pairArrayList.get(j));
                    servicesViewHolder.imageButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_remove));
                    servicesViewHolder.imageButton.setTag("Sub");
                    if(selectedList.size()>0){
                        myMenu.findItem(R.id.shoppingCart).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_shopping_cart);
                        itemsInCart=true;
                        Log.d("GetService", "onAdd: menu= "+myMenu.findItem(R.id.shoppingCart).getIcon());
                    }
                }else {
                    servicesViewHolder.imageButton.setTag("Add");
                    servicesViewHolder.imageButton.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add));
                    selectedList.remove(pairArrayList.get(j));
                    if(selectedList.size()<=0){
                        myMenu.findItem(R.id.shoppingCart).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart);
                        Log.d("GetService", "onSub: menu= "+myMenu.findItem(R.id.shoppingCart).getTitle());
                        itemsInCart=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pairArrayList.size();
    }

    public class servicesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView Service;
        TextView ServicePrice;
        ImageButton imageButton;
        public servicesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Service=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.service);
            ServicePrice=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.service_price);
            imageButton=(ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

listItem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/service"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Service"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/service_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Price"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/service"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:tag="Add"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:contentDescription="Add To Cart"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:focusable="true" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

After logging I realised that the button was being pressed each time but the code checking **getTag()=="Add"** was not working properly. Instead, on using **getTag().equals("Add")** works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of `String` equality and comparison, made less obvious by a quirk of Java. Essentially, the Java compiler is "smart enough" to find String literals in your code and make them all refer to the same `String` object instance (as long as they have the same text). Consider these lines:

```
if(servicesViewHolder.imageButton.getTag()=="Add") {
```

```
servicesViewHolder.imageButton.setTag("Add");
```

The compiler sees both `"Add"` string literals and makes them *the same object*. But it **can't** do this for the tag you set in XML:

```
android:tag="Add"
```

This is a *different object*. That means the first time you click it, xml-"Add" `!=` java-"Add"... but from then on, java-"Add" `==` java-"Add".

You can solve this by always making sure to do string comparison using `equals()` instead of `==`.

---

Consider this program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "hello";
    String b = "hello";
    String c = args[0];

    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(a == c);
}
```

If I run this program by typing

```
java MyTest hello
```

I will see this output:

> ```
> true
> false
> ```

Even though all three strings are "hello". This is because of the same thing I mentioned above: the String that isn't just a String literal can't be found and optimized to the same object.